# How can I obtain the "latest" vid when on Revisioning's "View latest" tab?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using the [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module to handle content revisions and I am creating a custom block that needs the vid of the node that the user is viewing to generate the appropriate content. I was trying to use menu_get_object() to obtain this and it works fine for a node with no revisions.

When I have a pending revision in Draft that I am looking at via the "View latest" tab, the node->vid I obtain from menu_get_object() is the vid of the "current" version, not the "latest". What would be the best way for me to obtain the vid of the version that is actually being displayed to the user?

Comment: See also http://drupal.org/node/1081804#comment-4712598 for an example with Views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug into the Revisioning module to see how they are doing the check and adapted it for use in a helper function in my module. I first load the node using `menu_get_object()` and then call the following:

```
function _get_correct_revision($node) {
  if (module_exists('revisioning')) {
    if (_revisioning_load_op($node, 'view') == REVISIONING_LOAD_LATEST) {
      $vid_to_load = revisioning_get_latest_revision_id($node->nid);
      $node = node_load($node->nid, $vid_to_load);
    }
  }
  return $node->vid;
}
```

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1081804

Answer (score 1):

The project page for revisioning says that node_load will offer some extra attributes related to revisions and I think you are looking for:

```
$node->is_pending;
```

Comment: I don't have the $node object available to me in the block hook.

Comment: As you wrote in your own answer, you can get the node object of the current page with menu_get_object().